# Form builders for mobile devices

Tags: forms, java-me, survey, mobile-phones

We're going to build survey apps for rural development (in India) using cellphones, including some Nokia and Android devices.  For building and capturing user info, we're looking at [OpenXdata](http://www.openxdata.org/) (which is open source J2ME solution) and [exZact](http://www.iformbuilder.com/), (which works on iPhone/iPod Touch). We're also looking at [ODK](http://code.google.com/p/open-data-kit/).

What tools/framework have other users used for the same ? Did you use cellphones or custom devices? What phones worked for you ? What are the pros and cons of each?

P.S : We're looking to develop for devices in the $100 category so that a big number of such devices can be deployed in the field cost effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I found an open source solution (J2ME, FLASH and J2EE) from Nokia for

1. mobile
2. form creation
3. server side app

respectively.

http://www.nokia.com/corporate-responsibility/society/nokia-data-gathering/english/00-index

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use J2ME phones, I can highly recommend [OpenXData](http://www.openxdata.org). I worked on the project for many years, and have used it for many projects - some of which had nearly 1000 data collectors. I found the server very stable and never experienced any data loss.

If you wish to use Android phones, then I'd recommend [ODK collect](https://opendatakit.org/use/collect/), which still has a very active community.

If you have more questions on OpenXData, you can reach out on [our mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/openxdata-users).